# Using Generic/Text only driver for Zebra 170Xi4, how to send commands ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers

We are wanting to have a label feed after a print job is finished. I know this is possible to do within the Zebra driver, but the issue we had there is it won't select the paper size automatically from the printer.

Is there a way to convert/send the ZPL command using the Printer Properties->Printer Commands-> End Print Job?

The ZPL command I had found to feed a label after a print job is:

^XA
^FD 
^XZ

Insuring to put a space after the FD and each command being on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to print a blank label is to add a ^PH command on your original zpl spool.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OubDb.jpg

The ^PH command causes the printer to feed one blank label.

Comment: If we print multiple labels at a time wouldn't this print a blank label after every label?